# Commenting in a Gatsby website + wordpress CMS

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

I am new to both gatsby and wordpress yet I have to build a blog with them. I used the gatsby-source-wordpress plugin and everything worked just great until I needed to implement commenting. Then I came across this blog post https://porchy.co.uk/posts/adding-wordpress-comments-to-gatsby . I managed to pull comments but the problem came with allowing visitors post comment specifically allowing anonymous comments. I failed to implement it. Could anyone please walk me through the procedure?

I tried changing the discussion settings to allow people post comments without logging in with their email and password in wordpress but it did not work.